# ng build fails in dockerbuild on Teamcity but not localy

Tags: node.js, docker, angular-cli, teamcity

I build an angular application insight a docker container.
The DockerFile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12.22.12 AS build

ARG STAGE=dev
ENV STAGE=${STAGE}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./

RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install python -y

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build-${STAGE}

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If I run on my local machine the command

> docker build -t spa-application --build-arg=STAGE=prod .

then it works.

If I execute the exact same command on my TeamCity Server, I get a compilation error during ng build-prod:
[image]

I don't understand what the difference is... Also it worked on Teamcity the last couple months. The last successfull build there was in september though, but it worked there for several months.

Does somebody have an idea what the issue might be?

Comment: HI! I noticed that you don't use package-lock.json. So there's a chance that TeamCity uses slightly different set of npm dependencies. On your local machine docker uses internal layer cache instead of actually running npm install. TeamCity agent also may have it's own cache but it might got pruned (or new/another agent is used to run your build)

Comment: @BorisMarkov Thank you! adding package-log.json to the dockerfile as well solved the issue for me